# Edit Row In the Second Page of Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am having a problem in my gridview, my Gridview has a event of **OnPageIndexChanging**,
the pagesize of my gridview is **20**

once the record was reach 20 in the first page, the 21st-40th record will go to the second page, when I go to the second page, and I click the edit button in my gridview..
ex: I click the row for  **21st record** in gridview

the EditItemTemplate for that row is not showing, but I am not encountering a problem and my code is executing well when I am debugging it.

here is my code in **"EditRow"** in **Gridview_RowCommand**

```
protected void gridview_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{

        int iActiveIndex;

        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "EditRow":
                iActiveIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

                gridview.EditIndex = iActiveIndex;

                gridview.DataSource = emp.TrainingPrograms;
                gridview.DataBind();
                break;
         }
}
```

This is the code in **Gridview_OnPageIndexChanging**

```
protected void gridview_OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

        gridview.DataSource = emp.TrainingPrograms;
        gridview.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        gridview.DataBind();
}
```

Is there any possible solution with my problem?

Comment: could you plz post some more code ? also source code so it becomes easy for us to figure out the actual problem....

Comment: @MMTac - I already post a new code, is that enough?

Comment: i would like to see your html code..

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the EditIndex property is the xth row on the current page. Try doing `gridview.EditIndex = iActiveIndex % gridview.PageSize;`

Comment: @Destrictor - Well, that is a good approach..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EditIndex property of the GridView control refers to the Xth row on the current page, not the id of the row to be edited.

The proper row can be selected by taking the modulus of the rowindex by the pagesize as thus:

```
gridview.EditIndex = iActiveIndex % gridview.PageSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the proper index by adding page size .

```
Int32 ActiveIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.NewEditIndex) % gridview.PageSize;
gridview.EditIndex = ActiveIndex + gridview.PageSize;
```